# If element does not equal these, do this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I'm trying to execute

```
$('a').click(function egg (event) { 
  if ($this.is('#home') || $this.is('#art') || $this.is('#con') || $this.is('#port') || $this.is('#m2')) {

  }  else {
    event.preventDefault(); 
  }
});
```

I only want to execute "event.preventDefault();" if the element id does not equal the parameters that I laid out in the if statement, however, this just executes "event.preventDefault();" on all of the ".a" elements, how can I achieve the result that I'm trying to get?

Comment: Where are you defining `$this`? Also note your code can be simplified by using a single class on all those elements along with the `:not` selector.

Comment: Try `$(this)`, not `$this`.

Comment: I changed it to $(this), it still prevents the code that I'm not trying to prevent though, but thank you, I didn't see that error at first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be made quite a bit simpler if you use the `.not()` construct to exclude the specific IDs from the selection, and combine that list of IDs into a single selector as a comma separated list, instead of having to have a series of `.is(foo) || .is(bar)...`.

```js
$('a').not('#home, #art, #con, #port, #m2').click(function(e) {
 console.log("e.preventDefault will fire");
 e.preventDefault();
});

$('#home').click(function() { /* your code here */ });
$('#art').click(function() { /* your code here */ });
// ...etc
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="home" href="#">home</a>
<a id="art" href="#">art</a>
<a id="con" href="#">con</a>
<a id="port" href="#">port</a>
<a id="m2" href="#">m2</a>
<a id="other" href="#">other</a>
<a href="#">another</a>
```

The specific functionality you want on the `#home` etc links would still be added as a separate click event for each element, just as you presumably have it now; they won't pick up the `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 3):

Check this...

`$(this)` is the valid jQuery wrapper.Not `$this`

```
$('a').click(function egg(event) {
  if ($(this).is('#home') || $(this).is('#art') || $(this).is('#con') || $(this).is('#port') || $(this).is('#m2')) {

  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: That alerts "hi" on the page when i click any ".a" element, except for the ones in my id parameters, however, it still prevents the elements in my id parameter from working.

Comment: That alert is for testing. you can remove that.

Answer (score 1):

```
//place all links you want in the if part here
var goodLinks = ['home', 'art', 'con'];


$('a').on('click', function(e){

    var id = e.target.id;

   if(goodLinks.includes(id)){

     console.log('valid id');

   } 
   else{
     e.preventDefault();

     console.log("invalid id -- else");

   }

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But it still prevents the elements that I'm not trying to prevent.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Changed the function and created an Array for all allowed ID's. Scroll down to see the a tags in this example. I really hope that I get you right, but is this what you want?**

There you go:

```js
var allowed_ids = ['home', 'art', 'con', 'port', 'm2'];
var scroll_speed = 1500;

$('a').click(function(e) { 
  if ($.inArray( e.target.id, allowed_ids ) > -1) {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, scroll_speed);
  } else {
    alert("invalid! ID is not in Array!");
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
#content{
  height:1500px;
  background:grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
This is the top!
</div>
<a id="home" href="#">home</a>
<a id="art" href="#">art</a>
<a id="con" href="#">con</a>
<a id="port" href="#">port</a>
<a id="m2" href="#">m2</a>
<a id="other" href="#">invalid</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But it still doesn't execute my intended code. I have a jquery function that executes when ever the element with those specific id's are clicked, and when I tried your code, mine didn't execute, it just brings me to the top of the page when I click on it.

Comment: That is because the e.preventDefault() is in the "else" scope. You did not mention this before. What code should be executed?

Comment: All of the elements with id's in my parameter have a code like this $('#home').click(function() {
    
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 4000);
    
    
    
    
  });

Comment: what do you mean? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Check the updated fiddle please. Is this what you wanted or is it something else?

Comment: thank you for your help! I was able to solve it. It was a problem in another section of my code, thank you!